# Git merge get source branch name after terminal window was closed

Tags: git, git-merge

In Git how can I get the name of the source branch of a merge?

I started a merge yesterday, got conflicts which I did not finish resolving, then a windows update restarted my computer closing my terminal window.

Comment: By *source branch* do you mean "the name you passed to the `git merge` command"? As in, if you ran `git merge zorg`, you want to retrieve the literal string `zorg`? (I ask because usually that's not itself as interesting as the *commit hash ID*, which is easier to retrieve too.)

Comment: @torek Yes, exactly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Look at the first line of `.git/MERGE_MSG`.

#### Long-ish

Per comment, we have the following situation:

- Something—perhaps not you, or you'd probably remember what you did—ran `git merge string`.
- This merge had conflicts, so it stopped in the middle of the merge.
- Then, while you were working on that, something else did a machine restart (presumably safely but you lost context).
- Additional Git commands may or may not have been run, but you are still in the middle of the conflicted merge.
- You now want to get the *`string`* back.

There is only one place that Git has saved the literal string, and that's in the `MERGE_MSG` file in the Git directory.  If you have a typical setup and are in the top level of your work-tree, that's:

```
$ cat .git/MERGE_MSG
Merge branch 'A' into B

# Conflicts:
#   new-filename
```

The first line will read:

```
Merge branch 'string'
```

or:

```
Merge branch 'string' into <name>
```

where `name` is the name of the branch you were on when the merge started.  (The `into <name>` part is omitted if and only if `<name>` is the literal text `master`.  This is one of the few places in Git where the name `master` gets special treatment: it changes the default merge message slightly.)

If your Git directory (the repository proper) is somewhere else, use `git rev-parse --git-dir` to find it.

The raw commit hash ID is easier to get:

```
$ git rev-parse MERGE_HEAD
243e415273b34b1553ce5eaeb6a189595d322015
```

You can turn this into a set of branch names that point directly to this commit with `git branch --points-at`:

```
$ git branch --points-at MERGE_HEAD
```

but this *may* produce no names at all–e.g., if you ran `git merge` on a raw hash ID, or the branch name has been moved since then—or it might produce more than one name.  So that first line of `.git/MERGE_MSG` is probably the place to look.

Note, by the way, that you can view the commit(s) reachable from `MERGE_HEAD` with `git log` as usual:

```
$ git log MERGE_HEAD
```

This is sometimes a useful way to *see* what you are merging, depending on how many commits are on each "leg" of each branch:

```
$ git log --decorate --oneline --graph --boundary MERGE_HEAD...HEAD
```

With the repository I have been using, this produces:

```
* 243e415 (A) modify renamed file too
* 57b6097 rename in branch A
| * c8d5dd8 (HEAD -> B) remove orig-filename
|/  
o 3a5c9ae (master) add orig-filename
```

In this case, the visualization is probably sufficient, but in more complex graphs, adding `--left-right` may be helpful:

```
$ git log --decorate --oneline --graph --left-right --boundary MERGE_HEAD...HEAD
< 243e415 (A) modify renamed file too
< 57b6097 rename in branch A
| > c8d5dd8 (HEAD -> B) remove orig-filename
|/  
o 3a5c9ae (master) add orig-filename
```

Note how "our" branch, `HEAD` aka `B`, is on the right of the three dots `MERGE_HEAD...HEAD`, and some commits are marked `>` because they are on our branch.  "Their" branch, `MERGE_HEAD` aka `A`, are marked `<` because `MERGE_HEAD` is on the left of `MERGE_HEAD...HEAD`.

(The `--boundary` option adjusts the set of commits included in the `git log` output so that we see the last commit here, in this case, on `master`.  Without that this commit is excluded from the `git log` output.)